# how to change default planner for moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, ompl, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to change the default planner for moveit from LBKPIECE1 to ESTkConfigDefault. I have tried appending:

```
  default_planner_config: ESTkConfigDefault
```

to the end of my ompl_planning.yaml with no success. I have yet to find any other way to accomplish this from either the command line or through configuration files. My full ompl_planning.yaml file is copied below in case it is relevant.

```
planner_configs:
  SBLkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::SBL
  ESTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::EST
  LBKPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::LBKPIECE
  BKPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::BKPIECE
  KPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::KPIECE
  RRTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRT
  RRTConnectkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRTConnect
  RRTstarkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRTstar
  TRRTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::TRRT
  PRMkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::PRM
  PRMstarkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::PRMstar

manipulator:
  planner_configs:
    - SBLkConfigDefault
    - ESTkConfigDefault
    - LBKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - BKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - KPIECEkConfigDefault
    - RRTkConfigDefault
    - RRTConnectkConfigDefault
    - RRTstarkConfigDefault
    - TRRTkConfigDefault
    - PRMkConfigDefault
    - PRMstarkConfigDefault

  projection_evaluator: joints(shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_lift_joint)
  longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.05
  default_planner_config: ESTkConfigDefault
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174103/how-to-change-default-planner-for-moveit/) by [airplanesrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/18786/airplanesrule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can set default planner with configuration file on latest moveit@indigo -> https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/pull/625

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can choose your solver by using the [setPlannerId](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#a2516b6bd223faf5ce4031d766a51cb3d) member of your MoveGroup:

```
  move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("manipulator");
  // See ompl_planning.yaml for a complete list
  group.setPlannerId("SBLkConfigDefault");
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) on 2015-01-30**:
which planner is used when no planner Id is specified ?

**Comment by [marcoesposito1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/7591/marcoesposito1988/) on 2015-04-15**:
If you remove the line:

```
projection_evaluator: joints(shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_lift_joint)
```

the default will be RRTConnect, else LBKPIECE1.

I am also interested in a deterministic way to set the default planner.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-26**:
For the people who end up here looking up how to switch planners: you may need to set [setPlanningPipelineId](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface_1_1MoveGroupInterfaceImpl.html#a0cbcfb05452b2e7f79fcba5b6f59535c) too.